# Route 53 URL Forwarding to Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I got a record set in Route 53 redirected from `api.domain.com` to a load balancer for component X.
Now I got multiple components so I want to be able to do `api.domain/auth` which redirects to the `auth` load balancer. How would I configure this in Route 53 and is this even possible?

Answer (score 3):

`/auth` is the path component of an HTTP URL. Route53 is a DNS service that has no awareness of the application layer. You cannot use Route53 to handle this redirect. A few other options to accomplish this:

- Point `api.domain.com` to an Apache httpd or Nginx service that can perform path-based routing
- Use the new AWS API Gateway Service to perform the routing. You'd point `api.domain.com` at your API Gateway URL, then set up methods in the API gateway to route `/auth` to the appropriate service